# Where does the enmity between Shia and Sunnis stem from?

Tags: islam

Shia and Sunni muslims are frequently engaged in violent clashes with each other, particularly in Irak and Syria at the moment.

Where does this enmity stem from? Are the motivations mainly religious or political?

Comment: "Today", "at this time" - what exactly is the **history** question here? But historically speaking, bloody suppression of heresy (as opposed to heathens) is not exactly [unprecedented in Abrahamic religions.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_wars_of_religion).

Comment: Because they are human. (i.e. why do X kill each other these days? where x is anything else human (Americans, drug dealers, police, you name it)

Comment: I've heavily edited it to express the same question in a more appropriate manner. The question has value as there is a historical answer to the origin of their enmity which partly explains why it's still ongoing. Although it may be off topic as it's easily answerable through Google. If you are looking for the answer Deckard this article sums it up pretty well: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-middle-east-16047709

Comment: Edit is good, but I can't vote to re-open without evidence of preliminary research.  There is ample documentation of the Sunni-Shia conflict in history.

Comment: I was very shocked when I heard the news that "IS" have killed 1,700 Iraqi soldiers and 260 Syrian soldiers few weeks ago. And it made me wonder what's going on out there, and post this question. As you all pointed it out, now I see it is not a thoughtful question. It is just expressions of my feelings - shock, horror, curiosity ...